# Single line braces in checkstyle gives error

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I want Checkstyle in Java to not give me any errors for the following line of code -

`if (true) { return 1; }`

But it gives me errors, `'}' should have line break before.` and `'{' should have line break after`. My LeftCurly block is as follows:

```
 <module name="LeftCurly">
   <!-- Checks for placement of the left curly brace ('{'). -->
   <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
</module>
```

My RightCurly is as follows:

```
<module name="RightCurly">
  <property name="option" value="same"/>
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
</module>
```

My NeedBraces is as follows:

```
<module name="NeedBraces">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO,    LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE"/>
</module>
```

How do I allow single line blocks to have opening and closing braces on the same line? Thanks!

I'm using the Gradle Checkstyle plugin, Checkstyle version: 6.7

Answer (score 1):

Your right curly option "same" means something different:

> The brace should be on the same line as the next part of a multi-block statement

So for your case you should use the option `alone_or_singleline`:

```
<property name="option" value="alone_or_singleline"/>
```

See [rcurly](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/property_types.html#rcurly) for more.

Also it is always a good idea to think about a consistent code style which avoids having exceptions! So think about another developer that will insert code some month later into your block - would be easier when the block is not on the same line.

Comment: I still get the first warning that OP is mentioning `'{' should have line break after.`. What's the missing piece to avoid that?